# How get the controller from a view in MVC 6?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

In MVC 5 we used ViewContext.Controller which has now gone. Any ideas how to get the controller in MVC 6?
Additionally, I need a way in my base view to share some data between the view and the layout. The lack of WebViewPage.PageData (doing this) is also confusing. Is the ViewBag the only option?

Many thanks in advance.